# problem when saving flash media live encoder CS5 output

Tags: flash-media-server, flashmedialiveencoder

Greeting,

I have a problem with flash media live encoder CS5 that when I record a stream and save it to selected folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Flash Media Server 3.5\applications\vod\media\CHAT.flv)

I can se the file from flash media live encoder CS5 but when I try to stream it using flash professional CS5 and run it using FLVPlayBack through rtmp://localhost/vod/CHAT  it will tell me connection error or file not exist. I check the folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Flash Media Server 3.5\applications\vod\media) but the file is not there but when I brows the folder using  flash media live encoder CS5 I can see the file.

please advice me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the folder location by reinstalling FMS and I located in C: (C:\Flash Media Server 3.5\applications\vod\media).

It seems that there is a problem with security permission with windows 7.
by the way I installed FMS in 2 different pc but I had same problem.